# How to save data between page changes without posting (MVC 5)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a Session variable to persist data when user goes back to the page that has the data input form. Storing the Session data values is done in the controller, after user submits the form. This works fine, but the problem is if the user changes page without posting the form first, all data is gone. How can I store the data under this condition? Probably I will need a JavaScript that calls an Action in the controller and pass the data to be saved via Ajax call? Is it possible to have an example on how to do this? also, in what event should this be called? I'm fairly new to JavaScript, so any detail would be important. Bellow is part of the code: (For simplicity, I've omitted additional code that test for null, etc...)

```
// View
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:peachpuff">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/ReservSearch.cshtml", Session["ReservSearchModel"] as Models.ReservSearch);}
    </div>
```

```
// Controller
           [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult GetRates([Bind(Include = "DropOffLoc,DropOffDate,PickUpDate")] ReservSearch reservSearch)
        {
            Session["ReservSearchModel"] = reservSearch;
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why not use the framework how it was meant to be used?

Comment: In terms of "User Experience" I believe the best way would be to warn the user when leaving, rather than force-saving the form... a bit like on SO where if you quit in the middle of editing you lose it. Another idea would be to use cookie, client side, all JS.

Comment: @Jason: I don't know how the framework was meant to be used. All I know is that in the majority of forms that I see, the data is persisted between page changes.

Comment: @Tallmaris Maybe your app is more complex. Mine is kind of SPA. It wouldn't be nice to prompt the user if he is the middle of filling a search query but only needs to see the address of the company in the "Contact" page before submitting the page.

Comment: Have a look at [the last answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700453/how-to-call-a-function-after-textbox-lose-focus) It demonstrates how you can use the textbox blur event to call a javascript function.  In your situation you'd probably want to call an ajax method which would then populate your server-side session variable.

Comment: @BenJunior: what forms are you seeing where data is persisted between page changes? There's multi-step forms, but those are a series of posts. I've never seen one example of a site saving form data for you when you just willy-nilly click off to somewhere else on the interwebs.

Comment: @Chris Pratt I see your point. If the user clicks the "Contact" button, then click the browser's "Back" arrow to return, the data in the Index page is persisted. However, if he clicks "Home" instead, the data is gone. How can I prevent the data to be erased in this case?

Comment: @BenJunior: that is browser behavior. It's the browser that saves the form data as part of the browser history, when you actually follow it back. Once you request the page anew, that goes away. This is just simply not how the web works.

Comment: Auto-save is a practical example of what (I think) the OP is requesting. Google uses it in numerous places, e.g. you won't find a save button on a spreadsheet in Google docs; it just detects the changes and saves them. This can introduce an immense amount of complexity into an application, but there's nothing wrong with the general idea.

Comment: I appreciate all the comments and what I've learned here regarding the proper web functionality. For this specific project, (more of a web app than a web site) I think it is better to use the solution in the answer below to save the data when user leaves the page and restore when back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  window.onbeforeunload = savedata;
  function savedata()
  {
        var formElement = document.getElementById("myFormElement");
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "MyController/MyAction");
        request.send(new FormData(formElement));
  }
</script>
```

**Note:** This **does not** demonstrate **"the correct way"**. It just demonstrates a quick and dirty solution **for sending the data on the form to your backend, when the user leaves the pages**

**The backend ASP.NET MVC controller**

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    public void MyAction(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        //find your form elements and their value in this formCollection collection
        //and process them as required 
    }
}
```